# Problems with apostrophos using Phpspreadsheet to write xlsx

Tags: php, phpexcel, xlsx, phpspreadsheet

I fill out a spreadsheet with the information of a person, however, names like D'anna generate a problem in xlsx. D'anna has a square box in place of the apostrophe '. 
The form of writing that I use is this:

```
$writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($this->excel, 'Xlsx');
$writer->save('php://output');
```

and at the time of setting the value in the cell, I use:

```
$planilha->setCellValue(utf8_encode($value['name']);
```

For the other values, it works correctly, only for the apostrophe that generates problem. Can someone help me? thankful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this:

```
$worksheet->setCellValue('C25',utf8_encode("D'anna"));
```

And from the picture, you see it works as expected:

[image: D'anna picture]